# Is there a difference between 「どこからか」 and 「どこかから」?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, nuances

While reading a child's fairy book, I came across with the following sentence:

> 人間界に着いたおばけのドロロンは「人間いないかなー♪子供はいないかなー♪」子供の魂をさがそうと街をフラフラ。**すると、どこからかいい匂いが漂ってきました。**「なんて甘くて美味しそうな匂い…」

I googled and found someone saying *there's no difference* as in https://hinative.com/ja/questions/13674821 and someone saying that *どこからか、が自然です*。 as in https://hinative.com/ja/questions/1530368. And also someone says there's a difference between the two.

I want to know under what circumstances will we say the following sentences:

1. どこかから鈴の音が聞こえてくる。
2. どこからか鈴の音が聞こえてくる。
3. 物音が、どこかから聞こえる。
4. 物音が、どこからか聞こえる。
5. どこかから良い匂いが漂ってくる。
6. どこからか良い匂いが漂ってくる。
7. どこかから蚊が入ってくる。
8. どこからか蚊が入ってくる。

Comment: @istrasci you may want to check the edit you just made to the title :-)

Comment: Oops.  Somehow I read the title as `...difference between 「どこか」 and 「どこかから」?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どこからか and どこかから are interchangeable in your examples, and they are almost always so. But since どこからか is a set phrase, it tends to be used by itself, modified by nothing:

- 日本のどこかから来た人 (natural)
- 日本のどこからか来た人 (a little questionable to me; see the hit counts below)

In addition, どこからか sounds a little more *literary* to me.

Here are the numbers of examples from [BCCWJ](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/):

- **どこかから**: 122
- **のどこかから**: 24
- **どこからか**: 290
- **のどこからか**: 8